# Decoupling of models from flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Usually, I develop web-apps with ASP .Net Core but recently I had to create a python flask app using ORM with sqlalchemy. First, everything worked quite well. The trouble started when I tried to clean up the design and decouple the packages in order to be testable in unit-tests.

I ran into the problem, that a model class needs to derive from `db.Model` where `db` is already an object of class `SQLAlchemy` and is also tied to the Flask app-object. So, this all becomes basically a big ball of mud.

```
class User(db.Model):
    pass
```

As a C# developer I find that to be more than strange. How can I decouple data models from flask and sqlalchemy to be testable independently? Is there e.g. a way to programmatically register the model classes for SQLAlchemy?

Comment: you could just use sqlalchemy instead of flask-sqlalchemy

Comment: I added an answer but wanted to ask some clarifying questions.  The term "unit testing" has become almost ambiguous as I understand it.  Do you have a lot of logic in the models you are testing?  What kind of model test are you trying to setup without an active db connection?

Comment: You might like to look at the [Cosmic Python](https://www.cosmicpython.com/) book, which works through a decoupled, repository pattern architecture using SQLAlchemy and Flask.

Answer (score 2):

I think `python_user`'s suggestion is probably a start on what you want but more specifically there is [imperative-mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_styles.html#imperative-mapping).  Which lets you completely separate the tables from the classes.

The only issue with this is that if you want to use all the latest typing features being added to declarative then that won't work.

All that being said, after using sqlalchemy for a while, I also would avoid putting almost any logic into the db models at all.  I would just use them to describe the data members and the relationships.  Then put all logic into some external services.  That usually makes testing easier for me.